# TypeScript - Import Module (Non-Relative) From Custom Location

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Let's say I have the following directory structure:

```
- functions
   - functionOne
      - tsconfig.json
      - index.ts
      - package.json
      - node_modules
- layers
   - layerOne
      - tsonfig.json
      - index.ts
      - index.js (compiled index.ts)
      - package.json
      - node_modules
```

Within `functions/functionOne/index.ts` I am trying to import `layerOne` as such:

```js
import JenkinsCredentials from '@prefix/module-name';
```

Now, I know that TypeScript is going to be like "What on earth is `@prefix/module-name`. So, within the `tsconfig.json` I have put the following:

```
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@prefix/module-name": ["../../layers/layerOne"] 
  }
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module '@prefix/module-name' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

I thought setting the `baseURL` and `paths` would help with this? What am I doing wrong/what would I need to do to get TypeScript to map the custom module name of `@prefix/module-name` to the directory `"../../layers/layerOne"`

**NOTE:** The reason for the custom name is the Lambda Layer is referenced this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paths` keyword considers `.` as the path of the `tsconfig.json` file.

You need to set the `path` as:

```json
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@prefix/module-name": ["./layers/layerOne"] 
  }
```

So it doesn't matter where you call `import JenkinsCredentials from '@prefix/module-name';` from, it will always result in the same file.

Comment: I set the path to `./layers/layerOne`, however, I am still getting the same error. I restarted VS Code but still the same error message.

Comment: So the actual problem was the fact I had it at the root of my `tsconfig.json` and not under the `compilerOptions`. Sorry for the problems